# How to create 4 element arrays with google scripts

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet with projects with names and attributed values to each name.

I would like to create an array of arrays so that I can match names between projects.

I have tried looping through each row, but this is inefficient.

Another Idea I had was to create an object for each name (like a balance) and append to it.

```
Project | Person1 | Weight1 |Team1 | Person2 | Weight2 | Team2|....     
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 p1       Bill        .5     Tech      Alice     1      Analytical
 p2       Larry        1   Analytical  Bill     .5       Tech
 p3       Joe          2     Tech      Larry     1       Tech
....
nth proj.
```

My expected results are:

```
[p1,Bill,.5,Tech],[p1,Alice,1,Analytical],[p2,Larry,1,Analytical],[p2,Bill,.5,Tech]...
```

Comment: Well, at this point 12 people who are competing for opportunities to provide answers have viewed your question. My guess is that none of us can figure out the correlation between your data and your expected results. Take a second look and be careful to realize we can't see your data and we can't read your mind.  And you have not provided us with any code to help us figure what you really want.  I'd say the ball is in your court.

Comment: Sorry, beginner here with google scripts.

I am manipulating a google sheet doc, and linking several sheets together. 

I need to create arrays of data that contain names, projects. I need to be able to link projects to names.

I believe that the best way to do this is to create an array of (1 x 4) arrays with the project being the key element.

Comment: Okay that make more sense.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way of creating an array of objects or if you wish attributed values.

```
function arrayOfObjects() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('DocData');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange()
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var lA=vA[0];
  var rA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    var rObj={};
    for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++) {
      rObj[lA[j]]=vA[i][j];
    }
    rA.push(rObj);
  }
  return rA;
}

function displayArray(rA) {
  var html="<style>td,th{border:1px solid black;}</style><table>";
  for(var i=1;i<rA.length;i++) {
    if(i==1) {
      html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><th>%s</th><th>%s</th><th>%s</th><th>%s</th></tr>',rA[i].project,rA[i].type,rA[i].weight,rA[i].first);
    }else{
      html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',rA[i].project,rA[i].type,rA[i].weight,rA[i].first);
    }
  }
  html+='</table>';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'My Object');
}

function runOne() {
  displayArray(arrayOfObjects());
}
```

This is my data sheet: (top row is labels, second is headers the rest is data)

[image]

This is my dialog output:

[image]

I often use labels in my objects that provide correlation between values in spreadsheets and id's in html elements for web apps.  You needn't do this if you don't wish to.